# how to create table using for loop by user input values in javascripts

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, arraylist, html-table

I have form . I wish to display values in table by clicking on add button

note: values will be stored in arrays
Use for loop

```js
function loadTable() {
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      "<tr id='row'>" 
          for (var j = 0; j < users[i].length; j++) {
          $("#items_tbody").append(
              
                  "<td>" + items[i][j] +"</td>" +
              
          )
          +"</tr>"
          console.log(items[i][j]);
      }
      
    }
  }
```

```css
 table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
      <!-- <form action="" method="get"> -->
        <input type="number" name="id" id="id">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <button type="button" id="submit">Add</button>
        <table id="demo">
          
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      <!-- </form> -->
    </body>
</html>
```

trying to get headers in tr and tbody data in tr seperatly but using for loop how can I do this

Comment: `"<tr id='row'>"` doesn’t do anything; `+"</tr>"` doesn’t do anything; `"<td>" + items[i][j] + "</td>" +` is syntactically incorrect; `#items_tbody` doesn’t exist (you mean `#demo tbody`). This isn’t PHP. Free-floating HTML strings aren’t magically going to be turned into output. There are [several examples of how to do this online](//google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+js+generate+table+row+in+loop). Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var j = 0; j < users[i].length; j++) {
   $("#items_tbody").append(
      "<td>" + items[i][j] +"</td>" +)
```

What this does is not create a DOM element. Just a string.
Here's what you need to do:

1. Create a  element

> ```
> const tdElement = document.createElement("td");
> ```

2. Add text content of items[i][j] to the newly created element

> tdElement.textContent = items[i][j]

3. You can also add classes to the HTML element created using the classlist.add method
4. Now you need to append the element to the parent node like you already did using the appendChild method.

Here's the MDN guide. Please go through it for a clearer understanding
[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement#examples)